# How can I know how much virtual memory apache service is using

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I'm reading [this article](http://codebucket.co.in/apache-prefork-mpm-configuration/) about `Apache` mpm configuration tuning. And the author shows how to get the amount of Virtual Memory apache is using like this:

```
ps -A | grep apache
```

But this command shows me multiple apache processes:

```
11188 ?        00:01:36 apache2
17821 ?        00:00:02 apache2
23682 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23720 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23790 ?        00:00:01 apache2
23800 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23803 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23805 ?        00:00:01 apache2
23881 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23884 ?        00:00:00 apache2
23900 ?        00:00:00 apache2
```

Do I need to know how much memory single process uses or all of them to put in this formula:

> Generally number of MaxClients=(Total RAM memory – RAM memory used for
>   other process except Apache process) / (Memory used by Single Apache
>   process)

It looks like I need to know the memory usage for a single process, but for which one out of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `top` command, and look at the `RES` colum.

Optionally, you can also use this command to get just that column for all Apache processes:

`top -n 1 | grep apache2 | awk '{print $6}'`

To get the average memory for all Apache processes, you can do the maths.

This Bash one-liner will get your average memory usage:

```
PROC_COUNT=0;MEM_TOTAL=0;for MEM_NUM in $(top -n 1 | grep apache2 | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/m//'); do let PROC_COUNT++;echo $MEM_NUM;let MEM_TOTAL=$MEM_TOTAL+$MEM_NUM; done; let MEMAVG=$MEM_TOTAL/$PROC_COUNT; echo "----"; echo $MEMAVG;
```

Comment: What will it give me then?

Comment: Read the answer and you will find out.

Comment: thanks, but `top -n 1 | grep apache2 | awk '{print $6}'` shows no output

Comment: Run `top` and verify you have Apache running.

Comment: this `top -b -n 1 | grep apache` shows a list of apache processes, but this `top -n 1 | grep apache2 | awk '{print $6}'` shows nothing

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi was correct here. I have apache running, I am sure of this because it's serving my website, and `top -n 1 | grep apache2 | awk '{print $6}'` returns nothing. Debian 12.